# shortcut key is not in direct access on non-english keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

There is a shortcut key i want to use: `cmd+[`

Problem: in my keyboard `[` character is on `alt+8`

How am i supposed to simulate `cmd+[`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my keyboard `cmd+ğ` or `cmd+ü` combinations don't put `[` character in any text area but when it comes to hotkeys it works.